# Sending request iOS, responce status code: 500

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, odata

Hello I'm sending json data to odata server, but I get status code 500 in responce. Hence 500 is described as a server failure I was assured that server works fine. I googled a lot and I still cant figure out what is wrong... Here is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     //I found thet some people had troubles due to their url had some spetial characters inside, however this is not my case

     //Create POST Params and add it to HTTPBody
     [request2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [request2 setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
     [request2 setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
     [request2 setHTTPBody:jsonData];

     //authorization
     NSString *authStr2 = @"username:password";
     NSData *authData2 = [authStr2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSString *authValue2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Basic %@",[authData2 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
     [request2 setValue:authValue2 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

     //Create task
     NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request2 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
     if(error){
     NSLog(@"ERROR---0");
     }
     }];[dataTask resume];
```

Im glad for any idea where I could mess up, thanks very much!

Comment: status code 500 means its server side error

Comment: can It be something that it is http**s**://...?

Comment: Send the url request copy to your backend suport, and let them tell you if you are doing it wrong or not.

Comment: put the error all error here

Comment: are you use secure url?

Comment: `2016-08-09 15:18:14.385 App [1294:434475] Response:<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x155d4a30> { URL: https://something } { status code: 500, headers {
         "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
         "Content-Length" = 5537;
         "Content-Type" = "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8";
         DataServiceVersion = "3.0;";
         Date = "Tue, 09 Aug 2016 13:18:14 GMT";
         Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
         "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
         "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
         "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
         } } (null)`

Comment: It is internal server error.It is not your mistake.It is backend mistake.You need to send 200 status code instead of 500. I got same error. i solved.

Comment: I'm using secure url @Birendra